# Regex. Prevent two occurences of the same word, but only inside regex (not whole string)

Tags: regex

Let's say I got the following regex scenario.

Until the word `banana` occurs, the word `complete` may only occur once. After `banana`, there can be 0 up to an infinite amount of `complete`s. How do I achieve this?

```
complete.*?$banana -> fails as there can be an infinite amount of completes before banana
```

something like

```
complete (?!(?:complete)).*?$banana -> fails as there can't be any complete AFTER banana neither.
```

```
complete complete banana = FALSE
complete banana complete = TRUE
complete banana = TRUE
complete complete complete banana complete = FALSE
complete banana complete complete complete = TRUE
complete complete complete = FALSE (banana missing)
banana = FALSE (complete missing)
```

`complete` and `banana` should occur together but with infinite amount of symbols in between except other `complete`s

Comment: Should an input without "banana" match or not?

Comment: no! complete and banana should occur together in this order, but with infinite amount of symbols in between except other completes. After banana, there can be other complete strings.

Comment: What if rhere is no 'complete'?

Comment: @trincot The last testcase says `FALSE`.

Comment: how many bananas can there be?

Comment: "complete may only occur once". Is `banana complete` fail or success?

Comment: @jhnc maximum one banana and only in the order "complete -> banana"

Comment: It's essential to mention regex flavor/tool along with most regex questions. The function scope differs a lot amongst those. For example in modern JS or .NET regex you could use a variable length lookbehind: [`^(?=.*?(complete)).*?banana(?<!(?:\1.*?){2}).*`](https://regex101.com/r/DVbATu/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
^((?!complete).)*complete((?!complete).)+banana
```

`^` start

`((?!complete).)*` 0+ characters not "complete"

`complete`

`((?!complete).)+` 1+ characters not "complete" (to allow for the space)

`banana`

Comment: wow... at first glimpse and first testing your regex seems to solve it.

Comment: --------complete((?!complete).)+?banana------ 

seems to be it

Comment: the first **((?!complete).)** in your regex is redudant don't you think? Or maybe I'm missing sth.. but thx so much anyway for your suggestion!!

Comment: complete((?!complete).)+banana (missing the first section) would match true on complete complete banana.

Comment: This assumes you can have other words/characters in the string. EG: test 98complete65 test ---4banana6 would want to be matched. If you only ever have the words banana and complete in the string, then the regex can be simplified.